# Proof vector $\vec{x} + \vec{y} = \vec{x} + \vec{z}$ then $\vec{y}=\vec{z}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\vec{x}$, $\vec{y}$ and $\vec{z}$ be vectors in a vector space $V$. Prove that if $\vec{x} + \vec{y} = \vec{x} + \vec{z}$ then $\vec{y}=\vec{z}$.

No idea how to start.

Comment: Do you know how you would prove this for numbers? Look at the vector space axioms. (Presumably the sentence "Show that $S$ is a vector space" shouldn't be part of the question, as $S$ doesn't appear anywhere else.)

Comment: Transitivity? Either you mean something else or the equivalence relation that you're thinking of does not jump to my mind... It looks like *injectivity* of a map given by adding $x$, to me.

Comment: I didn't know about the Unicode character U+20D7 COMBINING RIGHT ARROW ABOVE until now. But you used it wrong: Combining characters have to go *after* the character you want to combine them with. It would be better to use LaTeX, though. (And in print, it usually works better to use boldface than an arrow above.)

Answer (score 2):

Let $\vec{x}, \vec{y}, \vec{z} \in V$, where $V$ is a vector space.

We are given that \begin{align}\vec{x}+\vec{y}=\vec{x}+\vec{z}\end{align}
Now since, $\vec{x}, \vec{y}, \vec{z} \in V$, we know they satifsy the vector space axioms.

From these axioms, consider the vector $-\vec{x}.$

Adding this vector to both sides of the above equation and simplifying using our vector space axioms yields

\begin{align}(\vec{x}+\vec{y})+(-\vec{x})&=(\vec{x}+\vec{z})+(-\vec{x}) \\ \implies(\vec{x}+(-\vec{x}))+\vec{y}&= (\vec{x} + (-\vec{x})) + \vec{z} \\ \implies \vec{0}+\vec{y}&= \vec{0}+\vec{z} \\ \implies \vec{y}&= \vec{z}\end{align}

I leave it to you to identify which axiom was used where (i.e. to fill in the reasons)

P.S.: In future, please try and provide us with your current effort when posting a question, as that might help us see how you reasoned the question out, which will make explaining it to you much easier :). This is, after all, a learning curve :)